# "PyODBC [Error 10054] : TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" with fast_executemany=True

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to upload a sql into a sql server running in a docker container.
Below is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: sqlserver
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Password123
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./sqldata:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./data:/app/scripts
```

And here is my python code to load the csv into db:

```
def connectSQLServer():

    # Set up the connection information
    server = 'localhost'
    database = 'SLQBook'
    username = 'sa'
    password = 'Password123'
    
    # Connect to the database
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password, autocommit=True)
    
    # Set up a cursor to execute SQL statements
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    return conn, cursor


def loadDataBulk(cursor, mapping, tableName, delim = ','):
    
    dataFileLoc = mapping[tableName.lower()]
    
    print("dataFileLoc=", dataFileLoc)
    
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    
    with open (dataFileLoc, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = delim)
        headers = next(reader)
        data = list(reader)[1:]
        
        query = 'insert into {0} values ({1})'
        query = query.format(tableName, ','.join('?' * len(headers)))
        
        cursor.executemany(query, data)
        
        print(f'{len(data)} rows inserted to the {tableName} table')


conn, cursor = connectSQLServer()
mapping = {"subscribers":"data/Subscribers.txt"}
loadDataBulk(cursor, mapping, tableName='subscribers', delim = '\t')
```

When i run this code, i am getting an error as:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054)')
```

Where as when I load the data without `cursor.fast_executemany = True`, or when I load the data one by one using `cursor.execute(query, data)`, the data is loading successfully, but very slowly. Can someone help me understand why this error is coming only when I bulk load data with `cursor.fast_executemany = True`.

Comment: Aside... the sa account's password is passed into the container using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable, not `SA_PASSWORD`. Have you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) yet?

Comment: Yeah, but the database is up and running. I am able to query it from IDE. I am able to query and load data using pyodbc. It's just when I am trying to load in bulk using `cursor.fast_executemany = True`, the issue is occuring.

Comment: perhaps you should not insert so many rows at once, i'm not sure how executemany works under the hood, but it can be something there

Comment: Yeah, i believe that is the case. When I try with a smaller subset, it works

Answer (score 0):

With `fast_executemany=False` (the default), pyodbc sends a separate INSERT statement for each row. This is the "safer" approach, but it can be slow.

`fast_executemany=True` tells pyodbc to pack the parameter values for all rows into a binary ODBC structure called a "parameter array" and send them (essentially) in one shot. This can speed up the bulk insert tremendously, but it can also run into problems with insufficient resources:

1. on the client side, the Python process can run out of memory, or
2. on the server side, the SQL Server instance may not have enough room to receive the parameter values all at once.

It appears that you are experiencing the latter.

The workaround is to send the rows in chunks:

```py
import csv
import io

csv_str = io.StringIO(
    """\
product_id,description,price
1,widget,7.99
2,gadget,11.99
3,pie,3.14
"""
)
reader = csv.reader(csv_str)
headers = next(reader)
data = list(reader)
chunksize = 2
chunk_number = 0
for list_index in range(0, len(data), chunksize):
    chunk_number += 1
    chunk = data[list_index: list_index + chunksize]
    print(f"chunk {chunk_number}: {chunk}")
"""console output:
chunk 1: [['1', 'widget', '7.99'], ['2', 'gadget', '11.99']]
chunk 2: [['3', 'pie', '3.14']]
"""
```